# Where is Sextante in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sextante-qgis-plugin

I am using QGIS 1.7.3 (can't get 1.8 to work on my WIN 7 64 OS) and I cannot find the Sextante plugin. I have found other plugins with no problems, accessing all the various repositories, I have a list of many to choose from several repositories but there is no Sextante although the Sextante website says it should be downloadable from the QGIS main repository. What am I missing, doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find Sextante at http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml.

Either download it from there and expand it to your .qgis/python/plugins folder, or add the address to your repositories.
But I can not assure that it is working as expected on 1.7.3.

Comment: It works fine with QGIS 1.7.3.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what folder I should expand the Sextante zip file into? There is a "python25" folder with several subfolders, there is no "plugins" folder that I can find. Thanks -

Comment: Depends on your operating system: On Windows XP under C:\Documents&Settings\<username>\.qgis\python\plugins, Windows 7 under C:\user\<username>\.qgis\python\plugins. Its not in the folders where the programs are stored.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks so much. And so far it seems to work OK on 1.7.3.